# How to call function after setState updated(callback)

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, promise, callback, hook

I want to setVoting before setVote then run sendVote. However anyway it run sendVote first. How can i solve it? I use React Hook... so it is difficult. Please help me!!! Thank you so much.

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setVoting(!voting); setVote(voting?vote-1:vote+1); sendVote();}}>
       <Ionicons 
        name= {voting?'md-star':'md-star-outline'}
        size={24} 
        color={'#aa4fff'} 
       />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   setVote(voting?vote-1:vote+1);
},[voting]);

useEffect(()=>{
   sendVote();
},[vote]);
```

...then remove the setVote and sendVote from onPress:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVoting(!voting)}>
       <Ionicons 
        name= {voting?'md-star':'md-star-outline'}
        size={24} 
        color={'#aa4fff'} 
       />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: ```setVote(voting?vote-a:vote+1);``` should be ```setVote(voting?vote-1:vote+1);```, notice **a**

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! But if i back the screen, vote will decrease because const [voting, setVoting] = React.useState(false); so how to save sate of voting?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the typo. For that issue, you will need to keep track of the variable in your parent component, pass it into this component, then use it in useState call instead of setting it to false.